# Excel VBA to Create Pivot Table from Table

Tags: vba, excel

So i am new to VBA and trying to learn on the fly for something that has come up on a work project and it is driving me nuts.

I have a macro to clean up my data and put it into a table and then I am working on a macro to take that table and turn it into a Pivot Table/Charts. The first macro creates Table1 on spreadsheet "DailyData". For reference, here it is:

```
Sub Format_Table()
Dim target As Worksheet
Set target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
target.Name = "DailyData"
Worksheets("DailyData").Range("AB:AB,O:P,C:K,A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
Worksheets("DailyData").UsedRange
Worksheets("DailyData").UsedRange.Select
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes)
tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"
tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"
tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Machine"
Worksheets("DailyData").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

My Pivot is ideally going to have "Part Number" as a row field, and then "Setup Hours" "Indirect Labour" "Labour Hours" "Standard Labour Hours" "Labour Efficiency" as Value Fields.

So far I haven't even been able to get one of the Value field to show up right let alone all 5. So my current attempt to get the first value field to show up right is as follows:

```
Sub sbCreatePivot()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set ws = Worksheets.Add
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "DailyData!Table1")
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(ws.Range("B3"))
With pt
    With .PivotFields("Part Number")
       .Orientation = xlRowField
       .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Labour Hours")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("Labour Hours"), "Labour Hours", xlSum
End With

End Sub
```

I really appreciate the help as I am very new to all of this and trying my best here but I just keep hitting error after error and am running out of ways to google it.

Thanks,
Tyler

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and just modifying it to work for your liking?

Comment: I recorded it but when I try it on a new worksheet, aka the next day of data that would be pulled and edited by the macro, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, I have made modifications to both functions to better utilize Excel's VBA capabilties:

```
Sub Format_Table()

Dim targetSht As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set targetSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
targetSht.Name = "DailyData"

With targetSht
    .Range("AB:AB,O:P,C:K,A:A").EntireColumn.Delete

    Set tbl = .ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=.UsedRange, XlListObjectHasHEaders:=xlYes)
End With

With tbl
    .TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"
    .HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"
    .HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Machine"
End With

targetSht.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub sbCreatePivot()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim targetSht As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

' set the target sheet
Set targetSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DailyData")
' set the Table (listObject)
Set tbl = targetSht.ListObjects("Table1")

Set ws = Worksheets.Add
' Modified line to set the Pivot Cache
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, tbl.Range.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(ws.Range("B3"))

With pt
    With .PivotFields("Part Number")
       .Orientation = xlRowField
       .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Labour Hours")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    ' Modified line
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("Labour Hours"), "Sum of Labour Hours", xlSum
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this replacing

```
.AddDataField .PivotFields("Labour Hours"), "Labour Hours", xlSum
```

with this

```
With .PivotFields("Labour Hours")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "0"
End With
```